# how can i close div automatic with notepad++

Tags: html, css, wordpress, notepad++

i got xml files like this:

```html
<div style='max-width: 1000px; margin: 0px auto;'>
          <div style='text-align: center; margin-bottom: 0px; font-size: 13px; font-size: 11px; font-family: Verdana; color: #535353;'>Werbung</div>
```

but 1 div did'nt closed.

how can i close div automatic with notepad++
i got another question
i got xml file have 4000 line

how can i find unclosed div tag in 4000 line

Comment: i didn't write code i got a lot of code like this in xml i need to auto close div with command

Comment: in that case, it's difficult to predict where to close the div specially when there's a lot of nested divs..

Answer (score 2):

If you want a good text editor. You should use some other text editors such [ATOM](https://atom.io/). But you should definitely just learn to close tags on you own rather than expect the editor to do it for you, specially if you are using Notepad++.

Give Atom a try, thank me later.

Comment: how can i close tag selected text with shorcode in atom ?

Comment: have you downloaded it yet? I am sure that if you have you would understand it.. download some packages that you may think fit your needs.. you can download packages to do almost anything. the atom community is big, so you will find lots of things.. but the [emmet package](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LOzw7WMpmjY) is your friend.

Answer (score 0):

if you want an auto closing tag text editor, use Sublime Text 2/3

as for my personal experience, it is the best text editor a web dev can use. with tons of useful extensions and plugins to ease your problems